# NuxtJS store state variables keeps returning undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I have a problem with the NuxtJs store it always returns undefined I found a lot of similar questions but none has fixed the problem. here's my code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state(){ 
        return{
            count: 500
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getCount: (state) => {
            state.count
        }
    },
})
```

then I tried getting it this way

```js
this.$store.getters.getCount
```

also tried this

```js
computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getCount'])
},
created(){
        console.log("count: "+this['getCount'])
}
```

here's the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt sets up a store automatically for you, so you don't need to instantiate your own store.

Remove the setup code:

```js
// REMOVE ALL THIS:
//
// import Vue from 'vue'
// import Vuex from 'vuex'
//
// Vue.use(Vuex)
//
// const store = new Vuex.Store({/*...*/})
```

And create `store/index.js` with the following contents:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  count: 500,
})

export const getters = {
  getCount: state => state.count,
}
```

Now, you can access the store in your components:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('count', this.$store.getters.getCount)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-store-example?file=store/index.js)

Comment: Nuxt automatically creates modules from the `*.js` files under `store/`. You don't need to import them, and no need to put them in any directory structure under `store/`.